# How to create a keyboard shortcut to a custom style

Tags: css, ckeditor, keyboard-shortcuts

I created some custom styles:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles', [
    { name: 'Advanced',  element: 'div', attributes: { class: 'advanced' } },
    { name: 'Future',  element: 'div', attributes: { class: 'future' } },
]);

editor1 = CKEDITOR.replace("editor1", {stylesSet: 'my_styles'})
```

I can see and select them in the Styles combo. How can I create keyboard shortcuts for them?  I can use "setKeystroke", but what should I put in the "command" string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an editor command from a style command. Then assign a keystroke to that command:

```
const advancedStyle = new CKEDITOR.style({name: 'Advanced', element: 'div', attributes: { class: 'advanced'}});
editor1.addCommand('advancedCmd', new CKEDITOR.styleCommand(advancedStyle));
editor1.setKeystroke(CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.ALT + 65, 'advancedCmd'); // Ctrl+Alt+A
```